# Where does spark look for text files?

Tags: apache-spark

I thought that loading text files is done only from workers / within the cluster (you just need to make sure all workers have access to the same path, either by having that text file available on all nodes, or by use some shared folder mapped to the same path)

e.g. `spark-submit` / `spark-shell` can be launched from anywhere, and connect to a spark master, and the machine where you launched `spark-submit` / `spark-shell` (which is also where our driver runs, unless you are in "cluster" deploy mode) has nothing to do with the cluster. Therefore any data loading should be done only from the workers, not on the driver machine, right? e.g. there should be no way that `sc.textFile("file:///somePath")` will cause spark to look for a file on the *driver* machine (again, the driver is external to the cluster, e.g. in "client" deploy mode / standalone mode), right?

Well, this is what I thought too...

**Our cast**

- machine A: where the driver runs
- machine B: where both spark master and one of the workers run

**Act I - The Hope**

When I start a spark-shell from machine B to spark master on B I get this:

```
scala> sc.master
res3: String = spark://machinB:7077

scala> sc.textFile("/tmp/data/myfile.csv").count()
res4: Long = 976
```

**Act II - The Conflict**

But when I start a spark-shell from machine A, pointing to spark master on B I get this:

```
scala> sc.master
res2: String = spark://machineB:7077

scala> sc.textFile("/tmp/data/myfile.csv").count()
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/tmp/data/myfile.csv
```

And indeed `/tmp/data/myfile.csv` does not exist on machine A, but machine A is not on the cluster, it's just where the driver runs

**Act III - The Amazement**

What’s even weirder is that if I make this file available on machine A, it doesn’t throw this error anymore. (Instead it creates a job, but no tasks, and just fails due to a timeout, which is another issue that deserves a separate question)

Is there something in the way that Spark behaves that I’m missing? I thought that spark shell when connected to a remote, has nothing to do with the machine you are running on. So why does the error stops when I put that file available on machine A? It means that the location of sc.textFile includes the location of where *spark-shell* or *spark-submit* were initiated (in my case also where the driver runs)? This makes zero sense to me. but again, I'm open to learn new things.

**Epilogue**

tl;dr - sc.textFile("file:/somePath") running form a driver on machine A to a cluster on machines B,C,D... (driver not part of cluster)

It seems like it's looking for path *file:/somePath* also on the driver, is that true (or is it just me)? is that known? is that as designed?

I have a feeling that this is some weird network / VPN topology issue unique to my workplace network, but still this is what happens to me, and I'm utterly confused whether it is just me or a known behavior. (or I'm simply not getting how Spark works, which is always an option)

Comment: How are you running spark-shell?

Comment: `./bin/spark-shell --master spark://machineB:7077`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So the *really* short version of it the answer is, if you reference "file://..." it should be accessible on all nodes in your cluster including the dirver program. Sometimes some bits of work happen on the worker. Generally the way around this is just not using local files, and instead using something like S3, HDFS, or another network filesystem. There is the `sc.addFile` method which can be used to distribute a file from the driver to all of the other nodes (and then you use `SparkFiles.get` to resolve the download location).

Comment: Thanks, I suspected that. So "including the driver program" - even if the driver program is outside the cluster? Is it documented anywhere? I know it needs to be accessible on all nodes, I just found it surprising it needs to be accessible also on the driver

Comment: Yah I know it's a little weird, local fs access is a bit funky in Spark. I'm not sure if it's documented anywhere but I'll take a look and if it's not in the docs I'll add it.

Answer (score 0):

Spark can look for files both locally or on HDFS.

If you'd like to read in a file using sc.textFile() and take advantage of its RDD format, then the file should sit on HDFS. If you just want to read in a file the normal way, it is the same as you do depending on the API (Scala, Java, Python).

If you submit a local file with your driver, then addFile() distributes the file to each node and SparkFiles.get() downloads the file to a local temporary file.