# Apache Spark throws java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, macos, apache-spark, gradle

I am trying to launch `spark-submit` from a machine that runs spark master, while I have the worker in a different machine:

- Machine A: spark master
- Machine B: spark slave

But it is always throwing an Exception: `java.io.FileNotFoundException`

```
19/10/30 18:19:00 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, 130.229.129.193, executor 0): java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/private/var/folders/mf/hvtcpzmx6s39n7xc9182fxvc0000gp/T/spark-2237692a-95c1-4355-90fe-ed4524040879/userFiles-c1150981-0e3b-4b6f-a951-5783c1d14db8/data.csv does not exist
```

The Exception is not thrown when I run the master and the worker in the same machine. I understand that the problem is related with the file location, but I am using the [combination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32464894/where-does-spark-look-for-text-files?rq=1):

- sparkContext.addFile(fileName)
- and SparkFile.get(fileName)

So, the added file should be downloaded with this Spark job on every node no?

I don't want to try an alternative solution (S3, HDFS, ...), I just want to figure out what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

The java code I am using:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String fileName = "data.csv";

        //Count words and lines
        countWordsAndLines(fileName);
    }

    public  static void countWordsAndLines(String fileName) throws IOException {

        // SparkConf object for describing the application configuration.
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
                .setAppName("Count file words and lines");
                //.setMaster("local[*]");  // Delete this line when submitting to a cluster

        // A SparkContext object is the main entry point for Spark.
        JavaSparkContext sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

        //Add a file to be downloaded with this Spark job on every node.
        sparkContext.addFile("https://sda6.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/test/" + fileName);

        // Get the absolute path of a file added through SparkContext.addFile().
        // SparkContext is used to read a text file in memory as a JavaRDD object.
        JavaRDD<String> csvFile = sparkContext.textFile("file://" + SparkFiles.get(fileName));

        // Count no of lines
        System.out.println("Number of lines in file = " + csvFile.count());

        sparkContext.stop();
    }
}
```

To run my application on a cluster, I am doing the following:

1. Create a new file `spark-env.sh`, inside apache spark conf folder, where I set `SPARK_MASTER_HOST='machine-A-IP'`. I do this in machine A and B.

(in the command line):

2. Start master (machine A)

```
/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.4/libexec/sbin/start-master.sh
```

3. Start slave (machine B) (and I can see the worker show up on the master's homepage in machine A)

```
/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.4/libexec/sbin/start-slave.sh spark://machine-A-IP:7077
```

4. Run spark-submit (machine A)

```
/usr/local/bin/spark-submit   --master spark://machine-A-IP:7077   --class Main   build/libs/spark-exercise-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: How did you run spark-submit? In cluster mode or client mode?

Comment: @PiyushPatel I edited the question with more information.

Comment: Where did you see that you can access local file from another node in cluster? I don't think you can.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, not sure this helps but Spark will often throw a FNFE when in fact it there is an underlying hidden AccessDeniedException